# Iterating over CssStyleCollection

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to iterate over the Style property of a control in ASP.NET. This is of type CssStyleCollection, which has a reference page on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.cssstylecollection.aspx).

There is some sample code on that page for iterating through the collection and getting both the keys and values for each item in the collection. It looks like this:

```
IEnumerator keys = MyText.Style.Keys.GetEnumerator();

while (keys.MoveNext())
{
  String key = (String)keys.Current;
  dr = dt.NewRow();
  dr[0] = key;
  dr[1] = MyText.Style[key];
  dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

I've tried using the first line in my code, but the compiler keeps saying that I need to specify a type argument for the generic type IEnumerator. Given that I'm trying to use sample code from Microsoft itself, I'm a bit confused!

Is anyone able to help me with iterating through a CssStyleCollection?

Comment: I've tried your code and it actually compiles here. IEnumerable supports iteration on non-generic collection, it sounds like it has something to do with the collection. MyText is a TextBox, a Label?

Comment: Hmmm, I guess it might be that I'm trying to do it as a control extension method. Maybe it needs to be in a page context to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try iterating like the following:

```
foreach (string key in MyText.Style.Keys)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = key;
        dr[1] = MyText.Style[key];
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
```